# How do I convert Unicode special characters to html entities?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, html-entities

I have the following string:

```
$string = "★ This is some text ★";
```

I want to convert it to html entities:

```
$string = "&#9733; This is some text &#9733;";
```

The solution everyone is writing about:

```
htmlentities("★ This is some text ★", "UTF-8");
```

But htmlentities can't convert all unicodes to html entities. So it just gives me the same output as the input:

```
★ This is some text ★
```

I've also tried to combine this solution with both:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

and:

```
mb_convert_encoding();
```

But this either prints and empty result, doesn't convert at all or wrongly converts the stars to:

```
&Acirc;
```

How to I convert ★ and all other unicode characters to the correct html entity?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#107985

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`htmlentities` won't work in this case, but you can try to `UCS-4` encode the string, something like :

```
$string = "★ This is some text ★";
$entity = preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($m) {
    $char = current($m);
    $utf = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4', $char);
    return sprintf("&#x%s;", ltrim(strtoupper(bin2hex($utf)), "0"));
}, $string);
echo $entity;
```

---

```
&#x2605; This is some text &#x2605;
```

---

[Ideone-Demo](http://ideone.com/BEAILc)

Answer (score 0):

this is better

```
html_entity_decode('&#122;&#322;');
```

output - zł